# Where can I go windsurfing or snorkeling in July in southern India?

Tags: weather-and-climate, diving, sri-lanka, water-sports, south-india

I'm visiting an event in Madurai, Tamil Nadu, India in July this year and I'm wondering whether I could add on a week at the beach afterwards.
I usually go windsurfing and/or snorkeling when I stay at the beach.

Now I've read that July is monsoon season, but I've also read that it depends very much on the location. I don't mind a short heavy downpour every other day or high humidity, but I want to avoid constant rain. 
I've also read that there is no wrong time of year to visit Sri Lanka since one coast is always dry no matter which direction the rain comes from, so if southern India isn't a good option, I'd be happy to get recommendations for Sri Lanka as well.

So the question is:
Where in southern India or Sri Lanka could I go for a 1-week stay at the beach in the second half of July with reasonably dry weather and the opportunity to go windsurfing and/or snorkeling?

Comment: `reasonably dry weather` Don't count on it during the monsoons, ever. If you are very  very lucky then maybe a day or two or else a full week of rain with no sunshine.

Comment: @DumbCoder Thanks for the info. Maybe someone else has an idea where we could go. It doesn't have to be a beach at the ocean either, it can also be at a lake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @DumbCoder. The surfing season ends in May as the monsoon starts in June. Lifeguards even prevent you from getting into the sea in June and July. Snorkelling in the lakes may also be a disappointment as the rains cloud the water and visibility is very low.

The East Coast of Sri Lanka is a bright spot though and places like Arugambay are great to try your hand out with the locals. Moreover, the East Coast is incredibly scenic.

Comment: +1 We figured this out as well and have booked a surf course on Sri Lanka. I'll say more once we are back.

Comment: We ended up windsurfing on the north west coast of Sri Lanka. The weather was nice and dry, the wind was a bit gusty and the bay was a bit too shallow, but it's definitely possible.